# Is it possible to run "native" code on top of a managed OS?

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system, virtualization

I was reading up on Midori and kinda started wondering if this is possible.

On a managed OS, "managed code" is going to be native, and "native code" is going to be...alien? Is it possible, at least theoretically, to run the native code of today on a managed OS?

Answer (score 3):

First, you should start by defining "managed" and "native". On a "managed" OS like Midori, the kernel is still ngen-ed (precompiled to machine code), instead of being jit-compiled from IL. So, I would rule that out as a distinction between "managed" and "native".

There are two other distinctions between "managed" and "native" code that come to my mind - code vrifiability and resource management.

Most "native" code is unverifiable, thus a "managed" OS loader might refuse to even load "native" images. Of course, it is possible to produce verifiable "native" code, but that puts a lot of limitations and in essence is no different from "managed" code.

Resources in a "managed" OS would be managed by the OS, not the app. A "native" code  usually allocates and cleans up its resource. What would happen with a resource that was allocated by an OS API and given to the "native" code? Or vice versa? There should be quite clear rules on who and when will do the resource management and cleanup. For security reasons, I can't imagine the OS giving any direct control to the "native" code to any resources besides the process virtual memory. Therefore, the only reason to go "native" would be to implement your own memory management.

Today's "natve" code won't play by any of the rules above. Thus, a "managed" OS should refuse to execute it directly. Though, the "managed" OS might provide a virtualization layer like Hyper-V and host the "native" code in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

By managed I assume you mean the code runs in an environment which does some checks on the code for type safety, safe memory access etc. And native, well, the opposite. Now its this execution environment that determines whether it can allow native code to run without being verified. Look at it this way: The OS and the application on top both need an execution env to run in. Their only relationship is that the top application is calling the underlying OS for lower level tasks but in calling the OS, its actually being executed by the execution env(which may/may not support code verification depending on say, options passed in compiling the code for example) and when control is transferred to the OS, the execution env again is responsible for executing the OS code(this environment might be another envionment all together), in which case, it verifies the OS code(because its a managed OS).

So, theoretically, native code may/may not run on a managed OS. It all depends on the behaviour of the execution environment in which its running. Whether the OS is managed or not will not affect whether it will run on it or not.If the top application and the OS both have the same execution env(managed), then the native code will not run on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a native code emulator can be written in managed code, but it's not running on bare hardware.

I doubt any managed OS that relies on software verification to isolate access to shared resources (such as Singularity) allows running unmanaged code directly since it might be able to bypass all the protections provided by the software (unlike normal OSes, some managed OSes don't rely on protection techniques provided by hardware).

Answer (score 0):

From the MS Research paper [Singularity: Rethinking the Software Stack](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69431/osr2007_rethinkingsoftwarestack.pdf) (p9):

> A protection domain could, in principle, host a single process
>   containing unverifiable code written in an unsafe language such as
>   C++. Although very useful for running legacy code, we have not
>   yet explored this possibility. Currently, all code within a
>   protection domain is also contained within a SIP, which continues
>   to provide an isolation and failure containment boundary.

So it seems like, though unexplored at the moment, it is a distinct possibility.  Unmanaged code could run  in a hardware protected domain, it would take a performance hit from having to deal with virtual memory, the TLB, etc. but the system as a whole could maintain its invariants safely while running unmanaged code.